# ember.js check all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox

Hi im learning ember and got stuck with checkboxes.

Heres my template (part):

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="cell-delete">
                            {{input type="checkbox" id=colorId name=colorId class="js-custom-checkbox" checked=allChecked}}



                        </th>
                        <th class="cell-star">
                            &nbsp;
                        </th>
                        <th class="cell-broadcaster">Author</th>
                        <th class="cell-title">Title</th>
                        <th class="cell-date">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    {{#each message in model.entities}}

                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell-delete">

                                {{input type="checkbox" id=trash name="trash[]"  tabindex= message.id class="js-custom-checkbox check1" }}

                            </td>
                            <td class="cell-star">
                                {{input type="checkbox" name=message.id tabindex=message.id class="starBox" }}

                            </td>
                            <td class="cell-broadcaster">
                                {{message.notification.autor.firstName}} {{message.notification.autor.lastName}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="cell-title">
                                {{#link-to 'notifications.details' message.notification.id}}{{message.notification.title}}{{/link-to}} {{#unless message.isRead}} (new) {{/unless}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="cell-date">
                                {{formatDateWithDistance message.notification.cdate}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    {{/each}}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And my question is how to enable action to check all checkboxes in this template?

Data for this are taken in router form json api:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {

model: function() {
    return  $.getJSON(ENV.apiHost + "/api/notificationdata/user/all");

},
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are actually interested in changing data on your model, you need to hook up the checkboxes to something. Right now, it seems like they would display, and you could check and uncheck them, but it wouldn't actually do anything besides change colors of a few pixels on your computer.

With checkboxes, you need to hook them up to a value in your current  controller. You do that by setting up a boolean in that controller, and binding it to the `checked` attribute of your checkbox. If that value in the controller was called `allChecked` it might look like this:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=allChecked}}
```

Once that is done, you could hook up one final checkbox to a controller property that would trigger the controller to change all the values associated with the checkboxes to `true`.

There really is not enough context here to give you an answer that you could immediately plug in and have it work. But your controller might look like this:

```
...Ember.Controller.extend({

  allChecked: null,
  allCheckedWatcher: function(){
    if(this.get('allChecked') === true){
      // function to set all the other properties to true
    }
  }.observes('allChecked'),

})
```

Be warned, the example above will only work to check all the boxes. It wouldn't uncheck them. It's very rudimentary and only included to illustrate the idea behind how it all works.

You might want to [read up on checkboxes](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_use-as-checkbox), then check out the part of the Ember TodoMVC where they mention [toggling all todos](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-all-todos) back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It gives me some more details and i must try it. What im trying to do is to check all checkboxes without making any changes to te model. I have a list of posts and i have checkboxes. when i check some of them and press button delete its deleting them. That works fine. All im trying to do now is to add a checkbox that will select all of them - dont have to change anything else.

BTW. i have other checkbox and there i want to make changes to model after selection. But my value is 0/1 not false/true. Will it work to?

Comment: I would use false/true on the checkbox property and just set an observer to watch that value and change the actual property to a 1/0 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Don's tips i have managed to do that so im posting my code for others:

first template:

-checkbox to selece/deselect all:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=allChecked}}
```

- list of checkboxes:

  ```
  {{#each message in model.entities}}
   {{input type="checkbox" id=trash name="trash[]" checked=message.isDrop  tabindex= message.id class="check1" }}

   {{/each}}
  ```

My router:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {

model: function() {

    return  $.getJSON(ENV.apiHost + "/api/forum/user/all");

},

afterModel: function(model) {

    model['entities'].setEach('isDrop', false);


},
...
```

And my controler:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
selected: false,

isDrop: false,

allChecked: null,
allCheckedWatcher: function(){
    var model = this.get('model');
    if(this.get('allChecked') === true){

        model['entities'].setEach('isDrop', true);
    } else {

        model['entities'].setEach('isDrop', false);
    }
}.observes('allChecked'),
....
```